# Compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[m]{\cos x}-\sqrt[n]{\cos x}}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For two positive integers $m$ and $n$, compute

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[m]{\cos x}-\sqrt[n]{\cos x}}{x^2}$$

Without loss of generality I consider $m>n$ and multiply the numerator with its conjugate. But what next? Cannot proceed further! Help please!

Comment: Have you considered L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: The question is most easily solved by using series expansions as shown in Claude's answer. However it is instructive to see that the question can be solved without any high level technique with simple manipulation of the given expression as I have done in my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. I really appreciate you made this comment. Being lazy is sometimes good ! Cheers and thanks. I upvote your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[m]{\cos x}-\sqrt[n]{\cos x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[m]{1+\cos x-1}-\sqrt[n]{1+\cos x-1}}{x^2}=$$$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1+\cos x-1)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1}{\cos x-1}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}-\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{(1+\cos x-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\cos x-1}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}= $$$$=-\frac{1}{2m}-(-\frac{1}{2n})= \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2m}$$

I applied: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^r-1}{x}=r$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} =\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $x$ is going to zero, expand $\cos x$ as a Taylor series (one term would be sufficient) and use the fact that, for small values of $y$, $(1-y)^a$ is close to $(1-a y)$ (this is also coming from a Taylor series). So, you will easily establish that
$\cos^{1/m}(x) = 1- \dfrac{x^2}{2m}$
Doing the same for $n$, you end with $\dfrac{m - n}{2mn}$
For sure this only applies if $m$ is not equal to $n$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh. Thanks for editing. Iam almost blind and, beside plain ASCII, everything is hard to me. Cheers.

Comment: First of all I am really glad to know that so senior people like you are available on this website. I am happy that I helped out in some way.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{\cos x} - \sqrt[n]{\cos x}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)} - \sqrt[n]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)}}{x^{2}} - \frac{\sqrt[n]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt[m]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)} - 1}{x^{2}} - \frac{\sqrt[n]{1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)} - 1}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/m} - 1^{1/m}}{x^{2}} - \frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/n} - 1^{1/n}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/m} - 1^{1/m}}{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}\cdot\frac{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{x^{2}}\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,- \frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/n} - 1^{1/n}}{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}\cdot\frac{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{x^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/m} - 1^{1/m}}{(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)) - 1}\cdot\frac{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{x^{2}}\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,- \frac{\left(1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2)\right)^{1/n} - 1^{1/n}}{(1 -2\sin^{2}(x/2)) - 1}\cdot\frac{-2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{(x/2)^{2}}\cdot\frac{(x/2)^{2}}{x^{2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{m}\cdot 1^{(1 - m)/m}\cdot (-2)\cdot\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{n}\cdot 1^{(1 - n)/n}\cdot (-2)\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
&= \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2m}\end{aligned}$

We have used standard limits $$\lim_{y \to a}\frac{y^{n} - a^{n}}{y - a} = na^{n - 1}$$ where $y = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2), a = 1$ and $n$ is $1/m$ at one place and $1/n$ at another place. Also we make use of the $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.