# Limit involving trigonometric functions

Tags: limits

Here is the question $$\lim_{x \to 0} {{(\cos x)^{1/2}-(\cos x)^{1/3}}\over(\sin x)^2}$$

My attempt:-> $\lim_{x \to 0} ({(\cos x)^{1/2}-(\cos x)^{1/3}})\cdot x^2/(\sin x)^2\cdot x^2 $

-> $\lim_{x \to 0} ({(\cos x)^{1/2}-(\cos x)^{1/3}})/x^2 $

->$\lim_{x \to 0} [(\cos x)^{1/6}({(\cos x)^{3}-(\cos x)^{2}})]/x^2 $

->$\lim_{x \to 0} [(\cos x)^2((\cos x)-1)]/x^2 $  using $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$

->$\lim_{x \to 0} [-2(\sin(x/2))^{2}]/x^2 $ using $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ and $1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$

-> $-1/2$ using $ \lim_{x \to 0} \sin x/x=1$

My answer is coming out to be $-1/2$ but the correct answer is $-1/12$. Please mention where is the mistake in my procedure and please guide me with correct way.

Comment: Better typesetting: Use backslash before common functions: `\lim`, `\sin`, `\cos`. Use `\to` instead of ->. Fractions: `\frac{a}{b}` to get $\frac ab$

Comment: @winther from next time i will do it .

Comment: Next time? You know you can edit your question?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\,\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}\tag{1}$$ We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\cos x)^{1/2} - (\cos x)^{1/3}}{(\sin x)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\cos x)^{1/2} - (\cos x)^{1/3}}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{\sin ^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\cos x)^{1/2} - (\cos x)^{1/3}}{x^{2}}\cdot 1\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\{(\cos x)^{1/2} - 1\} - \{(\cos x)^{1/3} - 1\}}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\cos x)^{1/2} - 1}{x^{2}} - \frac{(\cos x)^{1/3} - 1}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\cos x)^{1/2} - 1}{\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}} - \frac{(\cos x)^{1/3} - 1}{\cos x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t^{1/2} - 1}{t - 1}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}} - \lim_{t \to 1}\frac{t^{1/3} - 1}{t - 1}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\text{ (putting }t = \cos x)\notag\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right)\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)}{x^{2}(1 + \cos x)}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1 + \cos x}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{1 + 1}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{12}\notag
\end{align}
[Also see a related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/602636/72031).

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are treating your limits as if you already know that they all exist – but you don't, because taking your numerator and denominator separately, they both converge against $0$. Thus you would have $\bf{\frac{\to0}{\to0}}$ and this is problematic, because a priori you don't know if this will converge or diverge.
As you don't know if the limit exists, it may be problematic to freely use the rules you are using like $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$.

However, as your numerator and denominator both converge against $0$ and are differentiable, one possibility is to try **L'Hôpital**'s rule. L'Hôpital doesn't guarantee success, but in some cases leads to a solution – which yours is one of (and I suspect that using it is the goal of your exercise).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to factor the numerator as

$$\begin{align}
\cos^{1/2}(x)-\cos^{1/3}(x)&=\cos^{1/3}(x)(\cos^{1/6}(x)-1)\\\\
&=\cos^{1/3}(x)\left(\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\cos^{5/6}(x)+\cos^{4/6}(x)+\cos^{3/6}(x)+\cos^{2/6}(x)+\cos^{1/6}(x)+1}\right)\\\\
&=\cos^{1/3}(x)\left(\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\sum_{k=1}^6\cos^{(k-1)/6}(x)}\right)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\frac{\cos^{1/2}(x)-\cos^{1/3}(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\left(\frac{\cos^{1/3}(x)}{\sum_{k=1}^6\cos^{(k-1)/6}(x)}\right)\left(\frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x^2}\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\right)$$

Finally, the limit of interest is

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^{1/2}(x)-\cos^{1/3}(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac16 \times \left(-\frac 12\right)\times 1=-\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: apart from a change of sign everything is OK. You need to have $(\cos x - 1)$ in your second last equation instead of the $(1 - \cos x)$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to fix the typo. Hope you are OK with it. And +1

Comment: @paramnandsingh Of course.  And thank you for correcting the sign error.

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment. It just shows another way to approach this kind of problems.*

Taylor series are a good way to use.

Just start with $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Now, making the problem more general, use the generalized binomial theorem which will give $$\cos^a(x)=1-\frac{a }{2}x^2+\frac{ a (3 a-2)}{24} x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$$ So $$\cos^a(x)-\cos^b(x)=\frac{b-a}{2} x^2 +\frac{(a-b) (3 a+3 b-2)}{24}  x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Similarly $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$sin^c(x)=x^c \left(1-\frac{c }{6}x^2+\frac{c (5 c-2)}{360}  x^4+O\left(x^5\right)\right)$$ After long division $$\frac{\cos^a(x)-\cos^b(x)}{sin^c(x)}=\frac 1{x^c}\Big(\frac{b-a}{2} x^2 +\frac{(a-b) (3 a+3 b-2 (c+1)}{24} x^4 +O\left(x^5\right)\Big)$$